# How to pull base (old) price in module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml

Tags: magento2, price, catalog-price-rules

I'm looking to output a base original price for a configurable product with both "price" and "special_price" set. For simplicity's sake I'm concerned only about the first such linked product's attributes.

The problem is, I cannot pull the base "price" from inside list.phtml like I can from final_price.html. Only special (after discount) price is available. When I call **$_product->getPrice()** (or any other million methods) I always get 0 and a message:

Call to a member function getPrice() on null

But the very same method works fine elsewhere. What am I doing wrong there? Why is that price available inside Magento_ConfigurableProduct module but not inside Magento_Catalog module?

Edit: so it appears the data is being pulled from the main configurable product that has **"price": 0** and **"attribute_code": "special_price", "value": "170.000000"** attributes. So the question is, how can I pull the price data *for the first simple product* linked to that configurable product?